# C++ Read two different files with different delimiters

Tags: c++, operators, delimiter, ifstream, getline

I am new to programming and would appreciate any help for my current problem:
I would like to read two different files: inputA and inputB, where one has this delimiter ':' and the other ','.
The goal is to get the values for inputA and inputB and combine them to outputC.
I have been able to read the files individually (and add them to a 2 dimensional, either array dataA or dataB). But I want to combine my two scripts into one. So the idea is while inputA is open getline using ':' then store values into dataA and while inputB is open getline using ',' and store into dataB.
This is how my script looks sofar for reading either inputA or inputB:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef vector <double> record_t;
typedef vector <record_t> data_t;

istream& operator >> ( istream& ins, record_t& record )
  {
  record.clear();
  string line;
    getline( ins, line );
  stringstream ss( line );
  string field;
  while (getline( ss, field, ':' )) // use ',' when inputB is supposed to be read
    {
    stringstream fs( field );
    double f = 0.0;
    fs >> f;
    record.push_back( f );
    }
  return ins;
  }

istream& operator >> ( istream& ins, data_t& data ) // here distinction between dataA or dataB?
  {
  data.clear();
  record_t record;
  while (ins >> record)
    {
    data.push_back( record );
    }
  return ins;
  }

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  data_t data;
  ifstream infile( "inputA.pgm" ); // and inputB.csv should be here
  infile >> data;
  if (!infile.eof())
    {
    cout << "file could not be opened\n";
    return 1;
    }
{
  infile.close();

//Output data
      ofstream myfile;
      myfile.open ("output.csv");
      myfile << data[1][1] << "," << data[2][1] << "," << data[3][1] << "\n"; //output dataA 
      myfile << data[1][1] << "," << data[2][1] << "," << data[3][1] << "\n"; //output dataB 
      myfile.close();

     return 0;
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: First of all, C++ isn't a scripting language ;) what you are showing is the program code. Then I don't know about using the operator `>>` overloading style for converting your data, but I would use "normal" functions. For me it is really confusing. Next, you only read doubles, seperated with either `:` or `,`. Why not looking first, which delimiter is there? It is either `:` or `,` and then pass this value as a char to the function. You can also extend this to search the first char after the double and use this as the delimiter

Comment: Thanks for your help :). I am quit new and this is a code jumbled together of what I found on the internet. And yes I don't completely understand it but it was working for what I needed it to do. Which is read the file and store into an array.

Answer (score 1):

So I have developed somewhat an answer to my own problem. Just doing fstream and getline for inputA then inputB. Now I just have to convert the strings into doubles and then store into the arrays. Which I think I should manage.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inA("inputA.txt");
    if(!inA.is_open())
        cout << "File could not be opened" << "\n";
    string dataA;

    while(inA.good()){
        getline(inA,dataA,',');

        cout << "dataA " << dataA << "\n";
    }
    inA.close();

    ifstream inB("inputB.txt");
    if(!inB.is_open())
        cout << "File could not be opened" << "\n";

    string dataB;

    while(inB.good()){
        getline(inB,dataB,':');

        cout << "dataB " << dataB << "\n";
    }
    inB.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for the used delimiter like this:

```
istream& operator >> ( istream& ins, data_t& data ) 
// here distinction between dataA or dataB? Yes it should happen here :D
{
    char delimiter = find_used_delimiter(ins);
    data.clear();
    record_t record;
    while (foo(ins, record, delimiter)) // use here a function where you read the record and pass the char-delimiter
        data.push_back( record );

   return ins;
}

char find_used_delimiter(istream& ins) {
    string line;
    std::size_t found = line.find_first_not_of("0123456789."); // search for first char, which is not a double char

   if (found!=std::string::npos)
   {
       std::cout << "The first non-double character is " << line[found];
       std::cout << " at position " << found << '\n';
       return line[found];
   }

   // here you should do some error handling, if there is no delimiter
}

istream& foo(istream& ins, record_t& record, char delimiter) {
    record.clear();
    string line;
    getline( ins, line );
    stringstream ss( line );
    string field;
    while (getline( ss, field, delimiter )) // use ',' when inputB is supposed to be read
    {
        stringstream fs( field );
        double f = 0.0;
        fs >> f;
        record.push_back( f );
    }
    return ins;
 }
```

Warning, the code is not tested and should be more a guide.
For reference: [find_first_not_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_not_of/)

Comment: Thanks! I don't completely understand the code, however I do not want to look for any kind of delimiter, but specifically say inputA has delimiter ':' and inputB has delimiter ','.